# What has been eating up my drywall?

Tags: drywall

Something has been eating up my drywall. Even after patching the wall the thing returns to same spot and eats it up. From the picture above that same spot has been patched up 3 times. There is no residue left behind. My house was built new and is 5 years old.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything that "rubs" the wall here? We used to have an air mattress that was kept near a wall and when people used it, the fill port would rub the wall and "eat" in to the paint and drywall.

Comment: Is that mud on the surface? It looks raised on my phone or just missing paint ?I have had 2 labs that would gnaw on sheetrock when left alone. Is this indoors or outside?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind that could do such a clean job of it is insects, and even that's a stretch. There's no gnaw pattern to it. What's in this area? How is it used? How can that much damage be done without you noticing it when it begins?

Comment: There is nothing attached or rubbing the wall. It is indoors at the top of the staircase and in several other places throughout the the house. It starts as a little scratch or bite mark and as I keep patching it up it keeps eating/gnawing on it.

Comment: Insects would leave poop on the floor, and I'd expect a more dendritic feeding pattern. Did you use some bug tasty paint, or is there a sweating water pipe behind the problem areas? What about paint flecks on the floor?